# Set-up xampp to access by particular ip addresses only

Tags: php, xampp

How do I set xampp to be able to view webpages by only me and 2 specific IP addresses?

I googled and did not find a working solution. Please help.

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 123.45.67.89 98.76.54.321 
    #Allow from all
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put #Deny from all, just keep 'Allow from' and specify ip...

see this might be helpful
https://superuser.com/questions/656700/allow-specific-users-from-outside-my-intranet-to-access-website